# Where is the prosecc' name for killall in command line in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, kill, kill-process

I have such command for running the process.

```
 /usr/bin/php /home/hosts/example.com/html/www/protected/cron.php cron MessangerHandler
```

How can I kill this process by its full name, using killall.

```
killall -9 ***what name****
```

What command it should be (don't recommend me pkill, i know about it, but i want to use killall).

Comment: What for this forum than?- better to ask here than read lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pkill -9 -f PROCESS-NAME-PATTERN-HERE`, e.g. `pkill -f cron.php`.

Always be sure your proccess name pattern doesn't match with other processes that you do not want to be killed.

Comment: no no,  my question is what the prosecc name from MY example- i need to know where here the NAME  ("php" or what?) "/usr/bin/php /home/hosts/example.com/html/www/protected/cron.php cron MessangerHandler"